# Java SimpleDateFormat not parsing correctly

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm processing a list of dates from an input file, and I need to convert each from String to Date. Examples of the format:

9/2/2013 7:34:17 PM
1/13/2011 10:47:36 AM

Each time a line is read, the date is stored in the String variable `dateAsString`. Here's what I've got:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss a");  
Date myDate = format.parse(dateAsString);  
System.out.println(myDate.toString());
```

The output is incorrect:

9/2/2013 7:34:17 PM becomes Sun Dec 30 19:34:17 EST 2012
1/13/2011 10:47:36 AM becomes Sun Dec 26 10:47:36 EST 2010

It seems pretty straightforward, so I'm confused. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use yyyy instead of YYYY.

Comment: Ugh, so simple! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try 'yyyy' instead of 'YYYY'

Answer (score 2):

Capital 'Y' means a "week year" where 'y' represents the actual year. Try using `yyyy` instead.

For more formatting help, check out the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) API where they give you examples of the patterns to use.

**Extra Info**

Just in case you're wondering, a "week year" is a year where all the weeks in the year are whole weeks

Answer (score 2):

Your format is not correct, as you can see in Javadoc :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Use yyyy instead of YYYY for the year part